# Not able to change or display object properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the properties inside of object I received in function

```
handleData = (obj) =>{
    console.log(obj) // shows {name: 'Laura', type: 'file',date: '1 min ago'}
    obj.name = 'newName'; // doesn't work
    Object.assign(obj, {name: 'newName', type: 'newType'}) // if console log it shows {name: 'newName', type: 'newType'} missing date
}
```

What should I do? where's the problem? I couldn't figure out the problem :(

**Update:**

if I did this

```
obj.name = 'newName';
```

> I'm getting Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<

Comment: is this object mutable object?

Comment: This code works as expected for me. Perhaps some more context could shed light on what is not working for you.

Comment: Actually I don't know, how could I know that?

Comment: @Lauradelgado Show the original object before it is passed to the function and your function call with that object.

Comment: It's coming from file input, I can't change it

Comment: `obj = Object.assign({}, obj, {name: 'newName', type: 'newType'})` is this work for you ?

Comment: you shouldn't modified the `obj` you received, specially when it is an read only object. you can assign to a new object using `Object.assign({}, obj, { // new changes }`

Comment: if I did `Object.assign({}, obj, {name: 'newName', type: 'newType'}` it shows only `{name: 'newName', type: 'newType'}` :(

Comment: date may be a non-enumerable property. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'date')` and check if it is enumerable.

Comment: if name property is not writable, object.assign will also fail. If you are experiencing different behaviour, it maybe some older browser that you are using. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the last version of chrome

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this: assigning to a new var, instead of modifying the `obj` directly

```
handleData = (obj) =>{
    console.log(obj) // shows {name: 'Laura', type: 'file', date: '1 min ago'}
    const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    console.log(cloned ) // should shows {name: 'Laura', type: 'file', date: '1 min ago'}

    const modified = Object.assign({}, cloned, {name: 'newName', type: 'newType'});
    console.log(cloned) // should shows {name: 'Laura', type: 'file', date: '1 min ago'}
    console.log(modified) // should shows {name: 'newName', type: 'newType', date: '1 min ago'}
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, it doesn't work shows only {name: 'newName', type: 'newType'}

Comment: are you sure it is not other issue? checkout my pen: https://codepen.io/jeemok/pen/EREvLp

Comment: I really couldn't figure out the problem, I think this object immutable because it's coming from file input... maybe I don't know

Comment: maybe you can try deep cloning the object `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: `console.log(cloned )` getting empty object `{}` if I `console.log(obj)` I'm seeing data, OMG how is this happening

Comment: hmm that's interesting. can you describe more of the source - `obj`? so I can reproduce it

Comment: You can create a HTML input type file then you will get an object data

Comment: can you share with me your `<Input />` code? I couldn't exactly reproduce the input file: https://codepen.io/jeemok/pen/GGdmVv?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Date maybe a non-enumerable property. Check for

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'date')
```

And examine the result. The enumerable should be set to true for it to appear in console.log.

See [getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting undefined for  `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'date')` even though if I `console.log(obj)` i'm seeing data, why is this happening? is it because the object immutable... maybe I've no idea

Comment: date maybe defined in the prototype of the object. And not on the object itself. It is a little difficult to simulate your problem. But here is a CodePen you can play around with. https://codepen.io/vijayst/pen/JZLrqX?editors=0012

Answer (score -1):

```js
handleData = obj =>{
    console.log(obj)
    obj['name'] = 'newName'
    console.log(obj)
}
const data = {name: 'Laura', type: 'file',date: '1 min ago'}
handleData(data)
```

Comment: No, the data is coming from file input

Comment: Have you tried my code in your function? If the comment in your code is correct, the data should be the same and the output is the object with name: "newName'.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work I'm getting Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object